# Объекты, которые конструируются на основании app.config, правильно ли?

Tags: c#, .net

Правильно ли, внутри класса инициализировать поля на основании app.config или идеалогически вернее считывать app.config в основной программе, а потом вызывать нужный конструктор типа, передавая значения app.config?

Comment: `DbContext` из Entity Framework берёт из конфига строку соединения. Так что первый подход вполне используется.

Answer (score 4):

Я за второй вариант.

Чтение `app.config` и вообще знание о том, что он существует — не дело отдельного класса, разве что только если его задача — заниматься конфигурацией.

Пусть часть программы, ответственная за конфигурацию, читает её, и вызывает нужный конструктор. Разделение обязанностей — хорошая вещь.

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать для получения значений из `app.config` статический класс `ConfigurationManager` из пространства имён `System.Configuration`, то нет ничего плохого в том, что вы вызываете его прямо в конструкторе класса, т.к. `ConfigurationManager` - стандартный класс .NET. В своих поектах лично я довольно часто использую такой подход, однако следует предусмотреть два момента: во-первых, следует всегда контролировать возникновение `NullReferenceException` в случае, если конечный позователь вашего API по какой-либо причине не указал значения в `app.config`. Во-вторых, следует предусмотреть возможность передачи кастомных значений либо напрямую через контруктор класса, либо с использованием определённых публичных методов в классе. Например, так:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public String MyProperty { get; private set; }

        public MyClass(String myProperty = "Default")
        {
            if (myProperty == "Default")
            {
                try
                {
                    var configValue = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyPropertyDefaultValue"];
                    this.MyProperty = configValue;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    this.MyProperty = "Default";
                }
            }
            else
                this.MyProperty = myProperty;
        }
    }
```